# Can ASP.Net sqldatasource connected to accdb and the display Gridview be re-used in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013

I have been using ASP.Net IIS and the company requires us to switch to Sharepoint 2013 cloud and discard IIS+ASP.net

Just wish to know in the past, I
have ASP.Net sqldatasource connected to accdb and the display Gridview.

Can they be re-used in Sharepoint ? What are the things I need to watch out ? Thanks